# Piano practice log : are "categories" important?

Tags: practice

I just started logging my practice activities in a journal. My main purpose is to keep my mind dedicated in order to make the best use of my time.

I wonder whether/which categories are important : today I practiced sight reading for 15 minutes and a piece for 30 minutes. I started logging this, but working the piece meant mainly working on polyrythm, so I wonder whether I should count it as "piece" or "technique/rythm".

For those who keep a journal, do you use categories? Which are they? Should the "technique" category used only for "out of context" work? Does it really matter, after all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Categories are important, but they should allow for flexibility.  If you are filling out the same forms every day, it will quickly become monotonous and you won't continue with it.  Everyone does journals differently - some people only write the bare essentials while other people like to / need to verbalize their thoughts with paragraphs.

It's a good idea to frame out parts of your practice session - sight-reading, technique, repertoire, and improvisation.  But really, there are two basic parts to your journal (if you include nothing else): *what you worked on that day* and *what you want to work on next time.*

It's important to include goals for the *next* practice session so that you have a plan of attack.

Honestly, I wouldn't worry about the semantics of how you label things - the practice journal is for you to organize your goals, so as long as you understand what's going on, that's all that really matters.